# RStudio keeps on running code chunk with no output

Tags: r, rstudio, geospatial, spatstat

I was running a spatstat envelop to generate simulations sample, however, it got stuck and did not run. So, I attempted to close the application but fail.

[image]

- [RStudio diagnostic log](https://gist.github.com/malcolmng/adc3eefc97832d054e866ef9cc0cf3f7)
- Additional error message:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information

Comment: You should look again at what you wrote and ask yourself: "Will people who are not looking at my console have any notion of what I have written?"

Comment: How long did you wait before considering 'it got stuck' ? depending on the number of point un the ppp, envelope functions can take some time to finish

Comment: around 2k points for an 1hr and i gave up

Answer (score 0):

There are several typing errors in the command shown in the question. The argument `rank` should be `nrank` and the argument `glocal` should be `global`. I will assume that these were typed correctly when you ran the command.

Since `global=TRUE` this command will generate 2 * nsim = 198 realisations of a completely random pattern and calculate the L function for each one of them. In my experience it should take only a minute or two to compute this, **unless** the geometry of the window is very complicated. One hour is really extraordinary.

So I'm guessing either you have a very complicated window (so that the edge correction calculation is taking a long time) or that `RStudio` is hanging somehow.

Try setting `correction="border"` or `correction="none"` and see if that makes it run faster. (These are the fastest choices.) If that works, then read the help for `Lest` or `Kest` about edge corrections, and choose an edge correction that you like. If not, then try running the same command in `R` instead of `RStudio`.

Comment: Hm, another possibility is that the envelope algorithm is trying to print progress reports and `RStudio` is blocking them. Try setting `verbose=FALSE` to suppress the progress reports.